# Laravel Backpack Not Loading CDN Assets Properly

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I just updated to the latest version of backpack pro (2.0.20) and I'm having some issues with basset. To be clear this was a point upgrade so I was already running version 6 and didn't have this issue before. The issue is that the CDN assets are getting prepended with /storage/basset

```
<link href="/storage/basset/cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.2/css/all.min.css?ebe4b0ad4676" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

I'm not sure why/how it's doing this. Has anyone here seen this before and know how to fix?
I've already tried running php artisan basset:fresh and that's not working.

I've already tried running php artisan basset:fresh and that's not working.

Answer (score 0):

The prepended URL `/storage/basset` is fine here. Basset is supposed to save assets from CDNs and serve them from our server disk.

I doubt you are missing a storage link to make them accessible from the URL.

Try linking it with `php artisan storage:link`.
This should help!